# pass the date from outside as a parameter

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sh

This is my Linux script, I want to ask the user from outside what date is needed, then save that  date and run the script for that date.

```sh
#/bin/bash

cDt=$(date +"%Y%m%d")

cd /home/dwh_landing/temp
echo 'Process_Date,Outfile,Outpath,Process_hour,Process_Minutes,Infile' > ccn_daily_${cDt}.csv

cd /home/dwh_landing/etl_scripts/etl_logs/

awk -F',' '{print $1 "," $2 "," $5}' *ccn-json*${cDt}* | grep 'creditControl.json' | awk -F '/' '{print $0 "," $5}' |  awk 'match($0, /(\s\S*k)/ , a ) {print $0 "," a[1]}' >> /home/dwh_landing/temp/ccn_daily_${cDt}.csv

cd /home/dwh_landing/temp

cat ccn_daily_${cDt}.csv | wc -l >> ccn_daily_${cDt}.csv
```

now currently this script generate a csv for the current date files, I want to run this for a user request date,  can I pass parameters from outside?
any help could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by *outside*? Do you want to pass parameters when running the script? If so, you can run the script with

```sh
./myscript $(date +"%Y%m%d")
```

and use this argument with

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cDt="$1"

...
```

This is parameter number one, since the null parameter is the name of the script.

Also, you can validate a date string with

```sh
if ! date +"%Y%m%d" -d "$cDt" &> /dev/null; then
    echo "$1 - invalid date string"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: this script finds the files for the current date and executes(generate ) a csv for the current date. example file_20210201<file name>,                                                                              I want to generate the files for a random date example: genate the csv for the date 2021-01-27 then it should takes files on the day 27 january  not the current date

Comment: possibility to pass the date suffix from outside as a parameter to script

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then the answer contains the solution to your question. The only thing I have not specified is a check that this argument exists at all. You can do it with `if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then echo "no parameters"; exit; fi`.

Comment: You can pass the argument without `date` e.g. `./myscript 20210127`. To use a different date format, you can change the validation string

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use a while loop to read a date off the user until the date is compliant (date returns a code 0) at which point we break from the loop and execute your script (in this case myscript), passing the read date variable dat as a parameter:

```
while true;
do read -p "Please enter a date in the format i.e. 20210201" dat;
 if date -d "$dat" +"%Y%m%d";
 then 
      break;
 fi;
done
myscript "$dat"
```

Then in your script, amend the line:

```
cDt=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
```

to:

```
cDt="$1" # SEt cDt to the first passed parameter
```

Comment: I'd recommend `while true; do read -p "..." dat; userDate=$(date -d "$dat" "+%Y%m%d") && break; done; do_stuff_with "$userDate"` -- that way, the user can enter the date in any (valid) format, and the script can use the ISO date format for whatever it needs.